# WPF "IsMouseOver" Trigger not Displaying Button Correctly

Tags: wpf, button

I have two png images, triple-checked to make sure they are properly transparent. Here is the button style code:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="TrackingButton" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <!--Default Base-->
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Content">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <Image Source="Resources/Start_Base.png"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
                <!--Hover-->
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Content">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <Image Source="Resources/Start_Hover.png"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            <!--Default Style-->
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Transparent"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Transparent"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
```

Here is the default state of the button: [DefaultState](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYUr0.png)
But when hovered over, the button loses its transparency and a white border appears around the areas that are supposed to be transparent: [HoveredOver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJsTS.png)

I'm not sure what's going on here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get rid of the chrome, you could define your own custom `ControlTemplate`:

```
<Style x:Key="TrackingButton" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Image x:Name="img" Source="Resources/Start_Base.png"/>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="img" Property="Source" Value="Resources/Start_Hover.png" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```